# Multiple databases on a single SQL Server named instance

Tags: sql-server, database-design

**Background**: we are architecting a new way to organize data in our databases and the DB team is likely to go with a 'Core' database with common data specific to our business area, and a separate database for each application that needs this data. Lets say a single one would be 'MyApplication'. These databases would all reside on the same named instance on the same server.

**Question**: How can I surface the tables, stored procedures, and data from 'Core' into an application that is pointing to the 'MyApplication' database?

I'm aware we could have the applications reference the other database directly, but this complicates things for the applications and is not preferred. Our original idea was creating writable views in the 'MyApplication' database for all of the objects in 'Core', but there might be performance concerns with this route.

Comment: Have you looked at Synonyms?

Comment: You could use synonyms but could get out of hand if you have to use too many objects from Core.

Comment: Views have no runtime cost, they are inlined into the query plan. They have no representation in the query optimizer at all.

Comment: What specifically are the complications you are trying to avoid?

Comment: The complication we're trying to avoid is making the application frameworks aware they are traversing across multiple databases.

Answer (score 0):

If the complications you are trying to avoid are security and logical object separation for code readability, you might consider creating separate schemas in your CORE database for each of your applications.  You could also possibly employ [application roles](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb669062%28v=vs.110%29.aspx) to aid with security.